# Java SerialPortEvent issue: DATA_AVAILABLE calls faster then incoming data

Tags: java, events, serial-port, rxtx, serial-communication

I'm posting for the first time so I hope that I write everything according to the format.

Currently I'm working on a project using Serial Communication with RXTX between a java application and a measuring device. This works great, but now I want to catch the data that the device sends with events.

The code below works but has the following issue:
`DATA_AVAILABLE` will be called 4 times before all the data will be send.
I catch this in a string called `vBuffer` and I'm able to catch the data to get the full string.

Now I want to return this data (the full string), but cannot find a `SerialPortEvent` that will wait till all data is send to return this string.

In the example below I use `OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY` but this is called at the beginning of sending a command. This means that when sending the command for the 2nd time, the `OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY` event will return vBuffer with data from the first command, and immediately after starts the 2nd command. At 3rd time `OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY` sends the data from the 2nd command and starts the 3rd etc.

Is there a way in `DATA_AVAILABLE` to wait till all data is send, or is there another event that will be called after all data is send?

Extra info: A command is send with a `Stringbuilder` of chars to make sure the right format for the device is send. The lay-out of a command is as follows: `<STX><COMMAND><RTX><CR><LF>`.
Might I be able to catch the end by looking at when the command ends? If so, how?

Update: This is the code how I send a function:

```
  StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
  message.append(new Character((char) 2));   // STX (Start of Text)
  message.append("M");                       // Command character
  message.append(new Character((char) 3));   // ETX (End of Text
  message.append(new Character((char) 13));  // CR (Carriage Return)
  message.append(new Character((char) 10));  // LF (Line Feed)
  outputStream.write(message.toString().getBytes());
```

After this the `DATA_AVAILABLE` will kick in. But doesn't wait till all received data is done.

Edit: To bump this up, still not further with the problem.

**serialEvent Method :**

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
 {
  switch (event.getEventType())
  {
   case SerialPortEvent.BI:
   case SerialPortEvent.OE:
   case SerialPortEvent.FE:
   case SerialPortEvent.PE:
   case SerialPortEvent.CD:
   case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
   case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
   case SerialPortEvent.RI:
   case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
    if (vBuffer != "")
     {
      System.out.println(vBuffer);
     }
     break;  
   case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[40];

    try
    {
      while (inputStream.available() > 0)
      {
        int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
      }
      vBuffer += new String(readBuffer);
      System.out.print(new String(readBuffer));
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: You think that when all data are received? From your side.

Comment: Don't really know what u mean, but the String i receive contains measure data from the connected device. And that String I'm going to split. I've done this the hardcoded way (forced a sleep), but now trying to achieve this without having hardcoded pieces in between.

Comment: "Is there a way in DATA_AVAILABLE to wait till all data is send". I don't see you are sending anything, just receiving. You mean wait until all data are received?

Comment: Updated with the send function. The event will just catch the data that the device returns. The return string looks something like this: `MAH      ,L  0.0,W  0.0,H  0.0,E,K  0.00,D  0.00,E,F 0,D`.  Only it will be split in 4 pieces. DATA_AVAILABLE is not waiting for all the data to be send before it acts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a way to check the command set STX and ETX too see if the message is complete (ETX is in the end of the message). If this checks true, then I've got a complete message.

Issue solved!

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event)
{

 if (event.getEventType() == SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE)
 {
  System.out.println("Data available event received");

  try
  {
    int available = inputStream.available();
    byte[] readBuffer = new byte[available];

    if (available > 0)
    {
      inputStream.read(readBuffer);
    }

    messageBuffer = messageBuffer + new String(readBuffer);

    try
    {
      int start = messageBuffer.indexOf(new Character((char) 2));
      int end = messageBuffer.indexOf(new Character((char) 10));

      if (start >= 0 && end >= 0)
      {
        System.out.println("We found 1 complete message!!");
        System.out.println(messageBuffer.substring(start, end));
        _fireBufferEvent();
        messageBuffer = "";
      }
    }
    catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
    {
      System.out.println("IndexOutOfBoundsException, message not complete yet. Waiting for more data.");
    }
  }
  catch (IOException ex)
  {
    System.out.println("IOException while reading data:");
    System.out.println(ex);
  }
}
```